# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS move buttons for minimize maximize and close to the left

Tags: 20.04

Coming from good old trusty Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Made a skip and jumped right to 20.04 LTS. I find it rather annoying that the buttons for minimize, maximize and close are now on the right side. I also want to move the apps button, which is in the lower left corner, to the upper right corner.

Concerning the min/max/close buttons I did try using gconf-editor. Not worth installing it, there is no metacity... Has anyone already experience how to make the desired changes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Install gnome tweaks with command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` and in windows title-bar you will find placement option for the buttons, under title-bar buttons choose right or left for moving the buttons right or left on title-bar.
Hope this will answer your query.

Comment: ...its just a jump to the left! Yep, this worked with the buttons. However I can not set the applications button from the lower left corner to the top. Also: I found a function within gnome-twekas under "general" to turn the animations off. Deactivating the animations causes my gnome-tweaks to misbehave. Its getting spasms and close button won't work. Its flooding this error message: (gnome-tweaks:14687): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:17:32.682: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -23 and height 17

Comment: keep animation on, if you want to switch it off, reboot the system after doing so the glitch problem will be solved

Comment: Please complete your answer with how to move the app button to the right top side.

Comment: @vanadium: to the top left side, not right side. Im not sure if this can be done... Im waiting for someone to make a good comment too. BTW, Madhusudans advice with rebooting to get rid of the tweaks glitch worked. Yet, I should not touch the animations setting anmyore as this will re-trigger the glitch.

Comment: You are asking two questions, in the title there is only one question. You may want to edit your post and move the aspect of putting the app button to a new question. This site has the format "one specific question" - "one specific answer". By the way, note that you actually did refer to the right side in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

To move the applications button and make various other customisations to the launcher, install the Dash to Dock extension by michele_g
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/